# Improvements and advice for my Cache class

Tags: c#, cache

After reading a bit about the [System.Runtime.Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.aspx) in the .net 4 framework I've added a simple Cache class to my application.

Can I improve it or add additional useful functionality? Typing it out here I see that the cache checking is somewhat duplicated; could this be refactored?

Note: the two properties SuperUsers and TemplateLocation are just for an example of how the class would be used. Most properties would be a string or list.

```
/// <summary>
/// Cache class as singleton to make those often used 
/// values that may change just that bit more speedy.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// Jon Skeets' singleton http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx
/// </remarks>
public sealed class Cacher
{
    private readonly ObjectCache _cache = MemoryCache.Default;
    public CacheItemPolicy Policy { get; set; }

    private static readonly Cacher instance = new Cacher();

    static Cacher()
    { }

    private Cacher()
    {
        // expiration policy default
        Policy = new CacheItemPolicy 
        {
            AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(10.0)
        };
    }

    public static Cacher Instance
    {
        get { return instance; }
    }

    public string TemplateLocation
    {
        get 
        { 
            var loc = _cache["templatelocation"] as string;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(loc))
            {
                // hardcoded for test purposes
                _cache.Set("templatelocation", getTemplateLocation(), Policy);
                loc = _cache["templatelocation"] as string;
            }
            return loc;
        }
    }

    public List<string> SuperUsers
    {
        get
        {
            var superUsers = _cache["superusers"] as List<string>;
            if (superUsers == null)
            {
                // empty, so stick values in the cache
                _cache.Set("superusers", GetSuperUsers(), Policy);
                superUsers = _cache["superusers"] as List<string>;
            }
            return superUsers;
        }
    }

    private string getTemplateLocation()
    {
        // hardcoded for test purposes
        return @"C:\";
    }

    private List<string> GetSuperUsers()
    {
        // hardcoded for test purposes
        return new List<string> {"John", "Anne", "Mark"};
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        foreach (var cacheitem in _cache)
            _cache.Remove(cacheitem.Key);
    }
}
```

and using the class:

```
string location = Cacher.Instance.TemplateLocation;
List<string> sUsers = Cacher.Instance.SuperUsers;
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be a caching class for just those two objects superusers and template location?

Comment: no, i just used those as an example. I shall edit the code.

Comment: Some of your get properties do too much work for a property. They also have side-effects (caching) I would replace them with `GetSomething(...)` methods, or methods with even better names that do hint at side effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something you might consider is switching it to be a static class instead of a singleton.  The caching system itself is already performing the singleton process.

To add functionality, if you change it to a static class you can add helpers to extend caching directly onto the object(s) itself like myDictionary.Cache() and myDictionary.LoadFromCache().

Reflection frequently gets used where it shouldn't.  However, you could decorate the functionality to auto-infer the "namespace.class.variablename" which removes magic stings entirely and makes the extended functionality more fluent.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestions, could you expand a little on the second point - about extending onto objects?

Comment: Sure.  If on the static class you add a method like "public static void Cache(this Dictionary item, string saveAs)" then you can just call myDictionary.Cache("userlist"). (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx )

Answer (score 1):

What do you need the singleton for? You don't need it at all. Just use static members if there is always one instance of this class.

I think the responsibilities of storing keys and values, and of returning and creating cache values should be separated.